# How can I add a border without any effect on the other controls?

Tags: xaml, border, winrt-xaml, stackpanel, grid-layout

I tried surrounding my grid with a border this way:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
<Grid>. . .</Grid>
</Border>
```

...but when I do that, the TextBlock that formerly was at the top of my page, as well as the other Grids, get pushed all over the canvas - the Border surrounds my grid perfectly, but it causes these side effects. How can I add a border without any effect on the other controls?

My XAML is:

```
StackPanel
    Grid with 3 columns and four rows)
        TextBlock (GridRow=0, GridCol=0, GridColSpan=3)
        Grid (GridRow=1)
        Grid (GridRow=2)
        Grid (GridRow=3)
```

### UPDATE

Thanks to Davut; this is what works pretty well:

```
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="4" Margin="4" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="4" Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="4" Margin="4" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Not understand what is matter,just putting this line over your grid has what side effect?,<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

Comment: Yeah, that works pretty good; I'll add the exact XAML above.